# catkin_make --pkg

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Could please someone explains to me one thing. Currently, I am trying to install pkg for Astra camera from source git: https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera . Firstly, I downloaded the directory by using `git clone https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera`. Next, in the instruction, I have to build it by using `catkin_make --pkg`. However, as an argument, I am writing astra_camera and not ros_astra_camera (as the pkg name). While I tried to do `catkin_make --pkg ros_astra_camera` there was an error, that it couldn't find that pkg. So my question is how does that function work `catkin_make --pkg` and why it couldn't find the right name of the pkg, but only astra_camera (I do not have astra_camera pkg only ros_astra_camera).

While I am running: `catkin_make --pkg ros_astra_camera -DFILTER=OFF`, it shows me next error:
Packages "ros_astra_camera" not found in the workspace

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318215/catkin_make---pkg/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-11**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the full error?

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-03-11**:
I have updated the question

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-03-11**:
now if I am running `roscd astra_camera` it follows me to ros_astra_camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository/directory name is NOT the package name.

The package name is specified in two places:

1. [in the package.xml](https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera/blob/master/package.xml#L3)
2. [in the CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L2)

This is why `catkin_make --pkg astra_camera` is working, but not with `ros_astra_camera`.

The directory can actually have any name. But it makes sense to have it the same as the package, for obvious reasons...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-03-11**:
thank you, for the clarification